# Spring + Hibernate + JPA: remove entity reference in join table

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm facing a difficulty in developing a server in Spring (+ Hibernate + JPA) for a project.

The structure of the server (the part of interest in this case) is composed of catalogs composed of products that can have some related feedbacks.

Here I share the 3 entities:

**Catalog.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "catalog")
public class Catalog {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "catalog_user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "catalog_product",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "catalog_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")}
    )
    private List<Product> products;

    public Catalog() {}

}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Category category;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public Product() {}

}
```

**Feedback.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "feedback")
public class Feedback {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "feedback_user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 1)
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Rating rating;

    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    public Feedback() {}

}
```

The problem occurs when I try to delete some entities. What I want is:

- when I delete a catalog also the catalog references in the "catalog_product" join table should be deleted (but the product linked with the catalog should not be deleted);
- when I delete a product also the product references in the "catalog_product" join table and the feedbacks related to that product should be deleted;
- when I delete a feedback nothing happens.

In the business layer I have this operations:

**CatalogServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class CatalogServiceImpl implements CatalogService {

    @Autowired
    private CatalogDAO catalogDAO;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    public CatalogDTO findById(Long id) {
        Catalog catalog = catalogDAO.findById(id);
        return mapper.map(catalog, CatalogDTO.class);
    }

    public CatalogDTO findByName(String name) {
        Catalog catalog = catalogDAO.findByName(name);
        return mapper.map(catalog, CatalogDTO.class);
    }

    public List<CatalogDTO> findByUserId(Long id) {
        List<Catalog> catalogs = catalogDAO.findByUserId(id);
        Type listCatalogsType = new TypeToken<List<CatalogDTO>>() {}.getType();
        return mapper.map(catalogs, listCatalogsType);
    }

    public List<CatalogDTO> findAll() {
        List<Catalog> catalogs = catalogDAO.findAll();
        Type listCatalogsType = new TypeToken<List<CatalogDTO>>() {}.getType();
        return mapper.map(catalogs, listCatalogsType);
    }

    public CatalogDTO createCatalog(CatalogDTO catalogDTO) {
        Catalog catalog = mapper.map(catalogDTO, Catalog.class);
        Catalog catalogFromDB = catalogDAO.save(catalog);
        return mapper.map(catalogFromDB, CatalogDTO.class);
    }

    public CatalogDTO updateCatalog(CatalogDTO catalogDTO) {
        Catalog catalog = mapper.map(catalogDTO, Catalog.class);
        Catalog catalogFromDB;
        if(catalogDAO.exists(catalog.getId())) {
            catalogFromDB = catalogDAO.save(catalog);
        } else {
            catalogFromDB = null;
        }
        return mapper.map(catalogFromDB, CatalogDTO.class);
    }

    public void deleteCatalog(Long id) {
        Catalog catalog = catalogDAO.findById(id);
        if(catalog != null) {
            catalogDAO.delete(catalog.getId());
        }
    }

}
```

**ProductServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    public ProductDTO findById(Long id) {
        Product product = productDAO.findById(id);
        return mapper.map(product, ProductDTO.class);
    }

    public ProductDTO findByName(String name) {
        Product product = productDAO.findByName(name);
        return mapper.map(product, ProductDTO.class);
    }

    public ProductDTO findByCategory(Category category) {
        Product product = productDAO.findByCategory(category);
        return mapper.map(product, ProductDTO.class);
    }

    public List<ProductDTO> findByUserId(Long id) {
        List<Product> products = productDAO.findByUserId(id);
        Type listProductsType = new TypeToken<List<ProductDTO>>() {}.getType();
        return mapper.map(products, listProductsType);
    }

    public List<ProductDTO> findAll() {
        List<Product> products = productDAO.findAll();
        Type listProductsType = new TypeToken<List<ProductDTO>>() {}.getType();
        return mapper.map(products, listProductsType);
    }

    public ProductDTO createProduct(ProductDTO productDTO) {
        Product product = mapper.map(productDTO, Product.class);
        Product productFromDB = productDAO.save(product);
        return mapper.map(productFromDB, ProductDTO.class);
    }

    public ProductDTO updateProduct(ProductDTO productDTO) {
        Product product = mapper.map(productDTO, Product.class);
        Product productFromDB;
        if(productDAO.exists(product.getId())) {
            System.out.println(product.toString());
            productFromDB = productDAO.save(product);
        } else {
            productFromDB = null;
        }
        return mapper.map(productFromDB, ProductDTO.class);
    }

    public void deleteProduct(Long id) {
        Product product = productDAO.findById(id);
        if(product != null) {
            productDAO.delete(product.getId());
        }
    }

}
```

Now, when I try performing the operations of deletion of catalog or product an error of constraint key fail is triggered. For example trying to delete a product which has a reference in the catalog_product join table:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`e01`.`catalog_product`, CONSTRAINT `FKdx5j7bcx77t7h0hjw6tvoxmp1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `product` (`id`))
```

I don't understand if there's a way to set the relations between entities to make what I want in an automatic way with Spring, or if I have to remove records with reference manually before the deletion of the catalog/product.

Thanks a lot in advance to everyone!
Luca

Comment: Did you try to add `CascadeType.REMOVE` in your `@ManyToMany`?

Comment: But if I add it I think it will try to delete also the other entity related. For example, if I have a catalog composed of some products and I try to delete the catalog it will delete also the products, that is not what I want to have. The products can "live" also without a catalog linked, but to perform the deletion I have to delete all the references (in this case) of the catalog, and I don't know how to do this.